# Using props and other attributes with react component definition

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I have created a react component and I'm reusing it in other components.

```
<SC_Button label = "English" btnStyle = "sc-btn-default--sinhala mb-2" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

But function defined at onClick does not execute because it's with props passed to the component. I guess react reads onClick as a prop as well. I'm quite new to react.

Below way works. But I don't want to wrap my react component with an extra div due to a styling issue.

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick} >
    <SC_Button label = "English" btnStyle = "sc-btn-default--sinhala mb-2"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use props along with other attributes in react component definitions ?

Edit :

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import SC_Button from '../components/button';

class Home extends React.Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/page2');
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row sc-overlay sc-overlay-main">
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-xl-5 offset-xl-1">
                        <span className = "sc-overlay-main__left">
                            <span className = "sc-main-image">
                                <img src={require('../assets/dialog_logo.png')} />
                            </span>
                            <h1 className="mt-4">Welcome to MyDialog</h1>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-xl-5">
                        <div className="row sc-overlay-main__right">
                            <label>Choose your preferred language</label>
                            <SC_Button label = "සිංහල" btnStyle = "sc-btn-default--sinhala mb-2" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                            <SC_Button label = "தமிழ்" btnStyle = "sc-btn-default--tamil mb-2" />
                            <SC_Button label = "English" btnStyle = "sc-btn-default--english mb-2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

SC_Button Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class SC_Button extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <button type="button" className={`sc-btn-default ${ this.props.btnStyle }`}>{this.props.label}</button>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(SC_Button);
```

Comment: are you handling `onClick` inside you're react component?

Comment: Put alert like this <div onClick={alert('hi')} > and if see onClick is the issue or your function. I think you have to remove this.

Comment: @uday I'm using onClick inside the parent component.

Comment: can you update you're question with `<SC_Button />` code.

Comment: @AnilKumar It works. But on the page load, not once I click on the button

Comment: @uday Please see the updated section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<SC_Button />` component, or any custom component you make, doesn't automatically implement an event handler. You're essentially just giving it yet another prop, called `onClick`, that it just throws away. You have to use the callback you're passing it in the DOM elements it returns:

**SC_Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class SC_Button extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <button 
                type="button"
                className={`sc-btn-default ${ this.props.btnStyle }`} 
                onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            >
                {this.props.label}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(SC_Button);
```

There is no need to define a `handleClick` function in the component, since you will be passing it as a prop every time you instantiate one. This allows different instances to have different behaviors.

Comment: Since SC_Button is a reusable component, its onclick function is getting changed from page to page. Therefore, I want to implement the onclick functionality in the component where we use SC_Button component, not in the SC_Button component. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Exactly! Whenever you use use one of these components, you'll need to pass it a function that it will use when it is clicked: `<SC_Button onClick={() => console.log('You clicked me!'} btnStyle={styles.something} label="aButton" />`